# How could I save an img in my express server that I receive from my client?

Tags: node.js, image, express, buffer, form-data

I have a client in React that sends a form data with a file. When that file arrives to the server, the body is parsed by body parser and its result is a buffer. The idea is that the file keep saved in some place of my server, because I want to use it later from my client. So I'd like to know how should I handle this problem.

I tried to write directly this buffer as a file with fs, but the file created has an error of format, so I can't access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do stuff like this

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('newImage', req.files.image, function (err) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log("It's saved");
});
```

correct parameter order of `fs.writeFile` is the filename first then the content.

If you're using `express.bodyParser()` you'll have the uploaded files in the req.files field.

And of course you should write the callback:

POV: *Your image file should be in req.files not the body.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a package for storing a file on your backend service. I had used [morgan package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan) for that and I was satisfied with using it. I have just searched other packages for storing a file, i found [express-fileupload package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload). Maybe you want to look at how to use those. If you want to store a file, using the third package would be better for you and for your effort.